# Problem with changing app language programmatically in Android

Tags: android, localization, resources

I created Settings Activity where I want users to change the app language inside this activity. I created all the resources for these languages. When I go to Settings Activity and change the language let's say to Russian, the language inside this activity changes and when I go back to Main Activity the language is not changed yet. In order to change whole app language I have to go to About Activity to apply all these changes. About Activity has only a toolbar a few Text Views

Also, My Main Activity contains tab layouts with view pager where I added two fragments.

LocaleHelper class

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * This class is used to change your application locale and persist this change for the next time
 * that your app is going to be used.
 * <p/>
 * You can also change the locale of your application on the fly by using the setLocale method.
 * <p/>
 * Created by gunhansancar on 07/10/15.
 */
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

//Change App language in Settings Activity

```
 listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String selected = (String) newValue;
                Log.d("Selected", selected);
                if (selected.equals("0")) {
                    saveToPrefs("en");
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(SettingsPrefActivity.this, "en");
                    listPreference.setSummary("English");
                    listPreference.setValueIndex(0);
                    recreate();
                } else if (selected.equals("1")) {
                    saveToPrefs("ru");
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(SettingsPrefActivity.this, "ru");
                    listPreference.setSummary("Russia");
                    listPreference.setValueIndex(1);
                    recreate();
                } else if (selected.equals("2")) {
                    saveToPrefs("uz");
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(SettingsPrefActivity.this, "uz");
                    listPreference.setSummary("Uzbek");
                    listPreference.setValueIndex(2);
                    recreate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    
        @Override
            protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
                super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase));
            }
```

Main Activity This code is called before on Create Change app language

```
   String languageCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Language", "en");
        if (languageCode.equals("1")) languageCode = "ru";
        else if (languageCode.equals("2")) languageCode = "uz";
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(TopActivity.this, languageCode);
```

Also created a separate class that extends Application and added to manifest application name

public class Home extends Application {

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base,"en"));
}
```

}

Comment: String languageCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Language", "en");
        if (languageCode.equals("1")) languageCode = "ru";
        else if (languageCode.equals("2")) languageCode = "uz";
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(TopActivity.this, languageCode);

Comment: Above portion code code need not be used anywhere except in SettingsActivity because this is the entry point where  actually Locale is updated.

Comment: Yeah, I removed them also, but didn't help.

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA Please help(((((

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might have visited [this](https://github.com/anurajr1/Multi-language_App). Well, one thing you have to do in each activity is just override below method. In About Activity just put below code and see the output:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
```

You could use this example code for better clarity.

Settings Activity is supposed to set the current language.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
Locale myLocale;
String currentLanguage = "en", currentLang;

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    currentLanguage = getIntent().getStringExtra(currentLang);

    findViewById(R.id.nextBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent refresh = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ViewPagerActivity.class);
            refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(refresh);
        }
    });
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Select language");
    list.add("English");
    list.add("Bengali");
    list.add("German");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setLocale("en");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setLocale("bn");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setLocale("de");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
public void setLocale(String localeName) {
    if (!localeName.equals(currentLanguage)) {
        Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, localeName);
        //Resources resources = context.getResources();
        myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
        startActivity(refresh);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Language already selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to move to some other activity to see whether language has been changed or not. Let's say I move to ViewPagerActivity.

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void attachBaseContext(Context context){
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(context));
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
}

public enum ModelObject {

    RED(R.string.menu_home, R.layout.fragment_home),
    BLUE(R.string.menu_gallery, R.layout.fragment_gallery),
    GREEN(R.string.menu_slideshow, R.layout.fragment_slideshow);

    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }

}

class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ModelObject.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
    }
}
}
```

Settings Activity xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
    android:text="Go to Next Activity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/common_text"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not putting ViewPager Activity xml here, because nothing important there you could create its xml using 1 View Pager. Now I want to show translated text in 3 Fragments which are included in View Pager adapter. Let's look one after another:
First, fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/menu_home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second, fragment_gallery.xml : This is similar to above layout but only text changes as below

```
 android:text="@string/menu_gallery"
```

Second, fragment_slideshow.xml : This is similar to above layout but only text changes as below

```
 android:text="@string/menu_slideshow"
```

Important: Only those strings will be shown as translated text which are defined in string  resources. And the name must match in every language folder.
For English, strings.xml file looks like

```
<string name="common_text">I Love Programming. Learning new language and developing android apps is one of my hubby.</string>
<string name="menu_home">Home</string>
<string name="menu_gallery">Gallery</string>
<string name="menu_slideshow">Slideshow</string>
```

For Bengali, strings.xml file looks like: Mark the name here all are same otherwise translation won't show.

```
<string name="common_text">আমি প্রোগ্রামিং ভালবাসি। নতুন ভাষা শেখা এবং অ্যান্ড্রয়েড অ্যাপ্লিকেশন বিকাশ করা আমার এক অন্যতম অভ্যাস।</string>
<string name="menu_home">বাড়ি</string>
<string name="menu_gallery">গ্যালারী</string>
<string name="menu_slideshow">স্লাইডশো</string>
```

For German, strings.xml looks like:

```
<string name="menu_home">Zuhause</string>
<string name="menu_gallery">Galerie</string>
<string name="menu_slideshow">Diashow</string>

<string name="common_text">Ich liebe das Programmieren. Das Erlernen einer neuen Sprache und das Entwickeln von Android-Apps ist einer meiner Ehemänner.</string>
```

Important: Whenever you enter into Settings Activity, make sure any activity which is launched from Settings activity must have `@Override public void attachBaseContext(Context context){ super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(context)); }` method. Because this method is called before onCreate(). Another scenario could be, if you launch Settings Activity from an activity and you want translation when you back to previous activity from Settings activity, then you have to launch previous activity. You can get to know which activity has launched Settings Activity by calling `getCallingActivity().getClass()` Like:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent previousActivity = new Intent(this, 
     getCallingActivity().getClass());
     previousActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(previousActivity);
     finish();
  }
```

Comment: I added it to AboutActivity but nothing changed. Also, I am using fragments with viewpager and TabLayout inside my MainActivity. Is the problem because of them?

Comment: Not only to About Activity, each and every activity should override this method if it has any translated text. Are you using same string name for all the languages ? Like: <string name="thank_you">Thank you</string> for default English, <string name="thank_you">Je vous remercie</string> for French. String name must be same in all language folder and this resource id must be used in order to display translation.

Comment: Can I see your LocalHelper class, please ?

Comment: Yeap, I am using the same string resources. I am 100% that resources are all correct. Also, I implement attachBaseContext on all activities except fragments coz the don't have this method

Comment: I added my LocaleHelper class!

Comment: please help brother

Comment: Sorry brother, I was busy in family work. I did not open my computer for 2 days. Have you fixed your issue ?

Comment: LocalHelper class looks fine.I am updating my answer just look at these code you might understand the issue.

Comment: let me try it brother

Comment: Oh, Thanks brother you solved my problem. The problem was not refreshing activity when I pressed back button.

Answer (score 0):

From the current code, I just put the working sample you need to adjust it according to your requirements I restart the app on language change to impact all Activities.

Need to override attachBaseContext in BaseActivity.

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.getInstance().createLocaleConfiguration(newBase));
    }
public void changeLanguage() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[]{"English", "Arabic"};
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int n) {
                    showLanguageChangeConfirmationDialog(items[n].toString());
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.setTitle("Which one?");
            builder.show();
        }
    
        private void showLanguageChangeConfirmationDialog(String selectedLanguage) {
            String languageName;
            switch (selectedLanguage) {
                case LANGUAGE_ARABIC:
                    languageName = getString(R.string.arabic);
                    break;
                case LANGUAGE_ENGLISH:
                default:
                    languageName = getString(R.string.english);
                    break;
        
    
        }
    
        DialogAlert dialogAlert = DialogAlert.getInstance(context);
        dialogAlert.setTitle("Change Language to " + languageName).setMessage("App will restart to complete this change.");
        dialogAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, which) ->
        {
            // update the value in the preference.
createLocaleConfiguration(context.getApplicationContext(), languageName);
            dialog.dismiss();
            restartApp();
        });
        dialogAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        dialogAlert.show();
    }
    
    public void restartApp() {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
            finishAffinity(); // Finishes all activities.
            startActivity(intent);    // Start the launch activity
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
```

Put below createLocaleConfiguration in any Singleton class to access it in BaseActivity or App class like anywhere you want.

```
public Context createLocaleConfiguration(Context context, String language) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(language)) {
                getSelectedLanguage(context);
            }
            Locale newLocale = new Locale(language);
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(newLocale);
                LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
                configuration.setLocales(localeList);
                configuration.setLayoutDirection(newLocale);
    
            } else {
                configuration.setLocale(newLocale);
                configuration.setLayoutDirection(configuration.locale);
                Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
            }
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
            return context;
        }
```